# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for localhost

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have created two separate files for login screen. one is loginpage.php where html code is there and another one is login.php which contains backend code. Both the codes were running fine and were giving proper output. But now it is not working, whenever I try to load the page it is showing this error-

> This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.
> Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I have almost tried doing everything like clearing cookies and cached files,
changing proxy server settings, running cmd commands.

re-installed xampp.

But still it is showing the same thing, and I am unable to find the problem in my code.

at first i was displaying all the errors using alert message. but that also i have changed and storing it in an array and display in the form. please help

LOGINPAGE.PHP

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Task Manager | Log in</title>
    
      <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
      <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
      <!-- icheck bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- Theme style -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition login-page">
      <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-logo">
          <p><b>Task Manager</b></p>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
          <!-- /.login-logo -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body login-card-body">
              <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
              
    
              <form action="login.php" method="post" id="login-form">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="EmailID" id="email" name="email" required>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                      <span class="fas fa-user-alt"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" required>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                      <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                      <select class="form-control select2bs4" name="role" id="role">
                        <option selected="selected">-select role-</option>
                        <option>ADMIN</option>
                        <option>EMPLOYEE</option>
                      </select>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <div class="icheck-primary">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
                      <label for="remember">
                    Remember Me
                  </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.col -->
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btn_submit" name="btn_submit"  >Sign In</button>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
              </form>
              <p class="mb-1">
                <br/>
                <a href="forgotpassword.html">I forgot my password</a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="error">
              <?php
              include 'login.php';
              if(empty($errormsg))
              {
                foreach($errormsg as $value)
                {
                  echo "$value";
                }
              }
              ?>
            </div>
            <!-- /.login-card-body -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`
      
      <!-- /.login-box -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="../plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="../dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the backend code for login screen

LOGIN.PHP

```
<?php
include('db_connection.php');
session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['admin_login']) && $_SESSION['admin_login'] != '')) {
    header("location:loginpage.php");
}
if(isset($_SESSION["employee_login"])){
    header("location:employee_dash.php");
} 
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);
    $role=strtolower($_POST['role']);

    if(empty($email)){
        $errormsg[]="Please enter email";
    } else if(empty($password)){
        $errormsg[]="Please enter password";
    } else if(empty($role)){
        $errormsg[]="Please select a role";
    } else if($email && $password && $role) {
        try {
            $query="SELECT email,password,role FROM `employee` WHERE email=? && password=? && role=?";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$query);
            
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sss',$email,$password,$role);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$email,$password,$role);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $dbemail=$row['email'];
                $dbpassword=$row['password'];
                $dbrole=$row['role'];
            }

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
                if($email==$dbemail && $password==$dbpassword && $role==$dbrole) {
                    switch($dbrole) {
                        case "admin":
                            $_SESSION["admin_login"]=$email;
                            header("refresh:1;dashboard.php");
                            break;
                            
                        case "employee":
                            $_SESSION["employee_login"]=$email;
                            header("refresh:1;employee_dash.php");
                            break;
    
                        default:
                        $errormsg[]="Invalid Role";
                    }
                } else {
                    $errormsg[]="Wrong Email or Password or Role"; 
                }
            } else {
                $errormsg[]="Records Not Found";
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->errorMessage();
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    } else {
        $errormsg[]="Enter the crendentials";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file or did you make amendments to it

Comment: you cant include login.php where your including it as it has session_start in it, also inside that file your redirecting to login if not logged in, but including it on login, hence the infinate redirects

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Use `exit` after `header("location`

Comment: Your `<form>` POSTS the inputs to the `action="login.php"` so you dont need to include that code in the `LOGNPAGE.PHP` page

Comment: waht do you have in dashboard.php and emplyee_dash.php, how you are checking if user is authenticated or not

Comment: i have not changed .htaccess file.

Comment: thankyou everyone for pointing out my mistakes. but please tell me what to do? do i need to change something or remove something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting to `loginpage.php` from the same page without destroying your session first, then it will keep redirecting from `loginpage` to `loginpage` as infinite loop.

try to check if session is populated and destroy it,
instead of:

```
if (!(isset($_SESSION['admin_login']) && $_SESSION['admin_login'] != '')) 
{
    header("location:loginpage.php");
}
```

You destroy any session already exit like:

```
if (!(isset($_SESSION['admin_login']) && $_SESSION['admin_login'] != '')) 
{
    session_destroy();
}
```