# This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times. Try deleting your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, codeigniter

I downloaded my CodeIgniter project from cpanel because i want to work on it. I paste the folder in htdocs of xampp start the Apache and mysql server of xampp, open my browser and type localhost/name_of_project and this error This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times.
Try deleting your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS occur.
this is the config.php file

```
    <?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    FCPATH . 'modules/' => '../../modules/'
);
ob_start();

$base_url  = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$base_url .= "://" . @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename(@$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", @$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/chuksb2b/";
$config['per_page'] = 5;

// Other configurations...

// Remaining configurations...
```

And this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/chuksb2b/$1 [R,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Other rules...
</IfModule>

Redirect 301 /xmlrpc.php http://127.0.0.1
```

I have changed the base_url to point to localhost/name_of_project and in .htaccess i have done the same thing but the error persist.
What else should i do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERR\_TOO\_MANY\_REDIRECTS for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859651/err-too-many-redirects-for-localhost)

Comment: without seeing the offending file(s), it is guess-work, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859651/err-too-many-redirects-for-localhost and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911808/error-310-neterr-too-many-redirects

Comment: AND It could also be an issue of your .htaccess configuration, check: http(localhost) versus https(production)

Comment: remove the redirect 301 line; I use: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]`